# jQuery append after into an element before

Tags: jquery

I am trying to move content to be after test2 but at the moment it's not working.

```
<div id="test">
    <div id="test2"></div>  
</div>

<div id="content"></div>
```

I'm using the following jQuery:

```
$("#test2").after("#content");
```

This is how `.after()` is meant to function? I've checked the jQuery docs and can't find what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are inserting the selector instead of the element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#content").insertAfter("#test2");​
```

will result in:

```
<div id="test">
    <div id="test2">b</div>
    <div id="content">a</div>  
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/DhRZA/)**.

Comment: Ah okay, it's always the small little problems!

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#test2").after($("#content"));
```

try this way

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#test2").after($("#content"));
```

will results in

```
<div id="test">
    <div id="test2"></div> 
<div id="content"></div> 
</div>
```

http://api.jquery.com/after/

Answer (score 1):

You were close, you just forgot to actually select the div

> ```
> $("#test2").after($("#content"));​
> ```

## Example

http://jsfiddle.net/DigitalBiscuits/F2dvB/